# Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["pod"] not found

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am trying to retrieve information from a json string that was converted from xml. I requested information from the wolfram alpha server about a "raven bird" and I would like to get the maximum recorded lifespan from the json string which is the information inside "alt". The life span seems to be inside of an array called "supbpod". The full json String is very long so this is the part that i am trying to retrieve information from

```
 {"scanner":"Species","subpod":[{"img":{"src":"http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP8471i7019ibc573d0d6000061c3540eaifae721?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=55","alt":"maximum recorded lifespan | 69 years  (in captivity)weight | 2.3 lb  (pounds)maximum recorded wingspan | 4.1 feet","width":391,"title":"maximum recorded lifespan | 69 years  (in captivity)weight | 2.3 lb  (pounds)maximum recorded wingspan | 4.1 feet","height":100},"plaintext":"maximum recorded lifespan | 69 years  (in captivity)weight | 2.3 lb  (pounds)maximum recorded wingspan | 4.1 feet","title":"Basic properties"}
```

Here is my code

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.json.*;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException, JSONException{//Beginning of class
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String appID = "";
    String search = "ravenbird";

    URL wolframData = new URL("http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?input="+search+"&appid="+appID);

    URLConnection connection = wolframData.openConnection();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    //reads in the data
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    String xmlDoc;

    while((xmlDoc = in.readLine()) != null){ //converts buffer reader to string
    str.append(xmlDoc);
    }
    in.close();

   JSONObject wolframJson = (JSONObject) XML.toJSONObject(str.toString());

    System.out.println(wolframJson.toString());//test

    try{
    JSONArray arr = wolframJson.getJSONArray("subpod");

    String lifespan = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
    {
        lifespan = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("alt");
    }
    }
    catch(JSONException je)
    {
        System.out.println(je);
    }





}//End of method

}//End of class
```

Since I have a try and catch statement in place, the message that prints out is :

```
 org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["subpod"] not found.
```

Here is the full json string is here:

```
 {"queryresult":{"server":23,"timedout":"Data,Character","pod":[{"scanner":"Identity","subpod":{"img":{"src":"http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP26821f9485ga5452748d00004353ab5216bid777?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=23","alt":"raven  (animal)","width":102,"title":"raven  (animal)","height":18},"plaintext":"raven  (animal)","title":""},"numsubpods":1,"id":"Input","position":100,"title":"Input interpretation","error":false},{"scanner":"Data","subpod":{"img":{"src":"http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP26831f9485ga5452748d000068f0hb74dh0ibg78?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=23","alt":"Corvus corax","width":83,"title":"Corvus corax","height":18},"plaintext":"Corvus corax","title":""},"numsubpods":1,"id":"ScientificName:SpeciesData","position":200,"title":"Scientific name","error":false},{"scanner":"Data","subpod":{"img":{"src":"http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP26841f9485ga5452748d00003f2a2979i5bf7079?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=23","alt":"kingdom | Animalia  (animals)phylum | Chordata  (chordates)class | Aves  (birds)order | Passeriformes  (perching birds)family | Corvidaegenus | Corvusspecies | Corvus corax  (raven)","width":310,"title":"kingdom | Animalia  (animals)phylum | Chordata  (chordates)class | Aves  (birds)order | Passeriformes  (perching birds)family | Corvidaegenus | Corvusspecies | Corvus corax  (raven)","height":228},"plaintext":"kingdom | Animalia  (animals)phylum | Chordata  (chordates)class | Aves  (birds)order | Passeriformes  (perching birds)family | Corvidaegenus | Corvusspecies | Corvus corax  (raven)","title":""},"numsubpods":1,"id":"Taxonomy:SpeciesData","position":400,"title":"Taxonomy","error":false},{"scanner":"Species","subpod":[{"img":{"src":"http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP26851f9485ga5452748d00004idia801fbf2gc35?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=23","alt":"maximum recorded lifespan | 69 years  (in captivity)weight | 2.3 lb  (pounds)maximum recorded wingspan | 4.1 feet","width":391,"title":"maximum recorded lifespan | 69 years  (in captivity)weight | 2.3 lb  (pounds)maximum recorded wingspan | 4.1 feet","height":100},"plaintext":"maximum recorded lifespan | 69 years  (in captivity)weight | 2.3 lb  (pounds)maximum recorded wingspan | 4.1 feet","title":"Basic properties"},{"img":{"src":"http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP26861f9485ga5452748d000019ed3b02h610c6bh?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=23","alt":"maximum recorded weight | 2.8 lb  (pounds)  (human: 1400 lb)","width":423,"title":"maximum recorded weight | 2.8 lb  (pounds)  (human: 1400 lb)","height":36},"plaintext":"maximum recorded weight | 2.8 lb  (pounds)  (human: 1400 lb)","title":"Physical dimensions"},{"img":{"src":"http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP26871f9485ga5452748d000024f3cche73be746e?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=23","alt":"cerebralization index (ratio of brain weight to spinal cord weight) | 19  (human: 170)heart weight | 0.5 oz  (ounces)  (human: 11 oz)","width":546,"title":"cerebralization index (ratio of brain weight to spinal cord weight) | 19  (human: 170)heart weight | 0.5 oz  (ounces)  (human: 11 oz)","height":85},"plaintext":"cerebralization index (ratio of brain weight to spinal cord weight) | 19  (human: 170)heart weight | 0.5 oz  (ounces)  (human: 11 oz)","title":"Internal organs"},{"img":{"src":"http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP26881f9485ga5452748d00002dd55i73e4hhd305?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=23","alt":"(typical values, except where otherwise noted)","width":249,"title":"(typical values, except where otherwise noted)","height":18},"plaintext":"(typical values, except where otherwise noted)","title":""}],"numsubpods":4,"id":"SpeciesDataPhysicalProperties","position":500,"title":"Biological properties","error":false,"states":{"count":2,"state":[{"input":"SpeciesDataPhysicalProperties__Show metric","name":"Show metric"},{"input":"SpeciesDataPhysicalProperties__More","name":"More"}]}},{"scanner":"Data","subpod":{"img":{"src":"http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP26891f9485ga5452748d00002770a3h7a323a24d?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=23","alt":"","width":150,"title":"","height":101},"imagesource":"http://www.eol.org/pages/1177364","plaintext":"","title":""},"numsubpods":1,"id":"Image:SpeciesData","position":600,"title":"Image","error":false},{"scanner":"Data","subpod":{"img":{"src":"http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP26901f9485ga5452748d000036642dd0802e73c9?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=23","alt":"Linnaeus, 1758","width":100,"title":"Linnaeus, 1758","height":18},"plaintext":"Linnaeus, 1758","title":""},"numsubpods":1,"id":"SpeciesAuthorithy:SpeciesData","position":700,"title":"Species authority","error":false},{"scanner":"Species","subpod":{"img":{"src":"http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP26911f9485ga5452748d000015b88iaiibid28c9?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=23","alt":"Corvus albicollis  |  Corvus albus  |  Corvus bennetti  | ...  | (total: 44)","width":447,"title":"Corvus albicollis  |  Corvus albus  |  Corvus bennetti  | ...  | (total: 44)","height":22},"plaintext":"Corvus albicollis  |  Corvus albus  |  Corvus bennetti  | ...  | (total: 44)","title":""},"numsubpods":1,"id":"SpeciesScannerOtherMembersOfSpecies","position":800,"title":"Other members of genus Corvus","error":false,"states":{"count":1,"state":{"input":"SpeciesScannerOtherMembersOfSpecies__More","name":"More"}}},{"scanner":"Species","subpod":{"img":{"src":"http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP26921f9485ga5452748d000056i1d379face7ei0?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=23","alt":"Corvus corax subsp. clarionensis  |  Corvus corax subsp. corax  |  Corvus corax subsp. principalis  | ...  | (total: 4)","width":522,"title":"Corvus corax subsp. clarionensis  |  Corvus corax subsp. corax  |  Corvus corax subsp. principalis  | ...  | (total: 4)","height":43},"plaintext":"Corvus corax subsp. clarionensis  |  Corvus corax subsp. corax  |  Corvus corax subsp. principalis  | ...  | (total: 4)","title":""},"numsubpods":1,"id":"SpeciesScannerMembersOfSpecies","position":900,"title":"Members of species Corvus corax","error":false,"states":{"count":1,"state":{"input":"SpeciesScannerMembersOfSpecies__More","name":"More"}}}],"sources":{"count":1,"source":{"text":"Species data","url":"http://www.wolframalpha.com/sources/SpeciesDataSourceInformationNotes.html"}},"timing":4.544,"parsetimedout":false,"profile":"EnterDoQuery:0.,StartWrap:4.54371","error":false,"version":2.6,"datatypes":"Species","related":"http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/api/v2/relatedQueries.jsp?id=MSPa26811f9485ga5452748d000049556951546128d6&s=23","success":true,"host":"http://www5b.wolframalpha.com","parsetiming":0.384,"id":"MSPa26801f9485ga5452748d00005188gd6e0f39c2h9","numpods":8,"timedoutpods":"","recalculate":"http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/api/v2/recalc.jsp?id=MSPa26791f9485ga5452748d00004gdcacbd2ge6efg1&s=23"}}
```

Comment: post your full stack trace

Comment: You've posted your API key. You'll probably want to revoke it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"subpod" is not an array in the full String. Use the normal get function to get "jqueryresult" then again to get "pod" , finally u use the GetJSONArray to get subpod.

edit;
example;

```
JSONOBject res = wolframJson.get("queryresult");
JSONObject pod = res.get("pod");
JSONArray arr = pod.getJSONArray("subpod");
```

edit2;
Lets assume we have the following JSON String.

```
{
"queryresult":
                {
                    "server":23,
                    "timedout":"Data,Character",
                    "pod":[
                            {
                                "scanner":"Identity",
                                "subpod":
                                            {"img":
                                                    {
                                                        "src":"dd"
                                                    },
                                                    "plaintext":"raven  (animal)",

                                            },
                            "numsubpods":1,
                            "id":"Input"
                            }

                          ]
                }
}
```

We cannot acces directly the Pod  elements, first we need to acces the "queryresult". If we call the get("queryresult"); method we will have the queryresult element.
so in the memory of the computer it will look like this:

```
                    {
                        "server":23,
                        "timedout":"Data,Character",
                        "pod":[
                                {
                                    "scanner":"Identity",
                                    "subpod":
                                                {"img":
                                                        {
                                                            "src":"dd"
                                                        },
                                                        "plaintext":"raven  (animal)",

                                                },
                                "numsubpods":1,
                                "id":"Input"
                                }

                              ]
                    }
```

Now we can acces the pod array.

Comment: Its not working, I am getting an error saying : JSONObject["pod"] is not a JSONObject

Comment: U have to think yourself to , u have to nest it.

Comment: What made you chose this approach. Can you explain?